# Keyboard configuration missing from System settings

Tags: settings

I don't know how I messed this up, probably with a bad aptitude configuration (my bad), but the "Keyboard" configuration item is missing from System Settings:

[image]

What package should I reinstall to have the keyboard settings back in system settings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reinstalling the packages `switchboard-plug-keyboard` and `wingpanel-indicator-keyboard` fixed the issue. Thanks for the person that helped me on IRC.